# Node-Red Credential Files - Missing and Now Errors

Tags: node-red

I found today that my node-red was running but the flows were not functioning properly. I got the credentials could not be decrypted error. My server has been up solid for quite some time functioning just fine and now recently I just noticed with said error. Upon exploring the folders of NR install, I cannot even see the credential file, and this leaves me rather suspicious. 
What could cause an encryption file to spontaneously disappear? 
I know I have a few installs on my system of NR, but only use one, and I was also curious how I could ensure I am looking in the right spot? ie how to know what directory your node red is being run.

I try this command :  readlink -f /proc/#(procID)#/exe  and only get the bin directory where Node is held.

I really hope my system wasn't messed with. I think at worst is I need to re-create the encrypted flows file, but I just want to make sure my system isn't tampered with somehow.

Thanks for any feedback regarding my situation.

[image]

Comment: ADDED: 
I figured a few things out, and just stuck with my original post.